# Watching python logs real time while running on webhosting?

Tags: python

I have a python script that is running on my site \ webhosting. I've activated it by going to the         url -> script.py. Is there a way to watch the logs the script outputs the way you'd see in the terminal if you'll SSH -> run `python script.py` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the 'tee' command, which will output to both stdout (i.e. your SSH terminal) and a file at the same time.

```
python foo.py | tee /tmp/foo.log
```

Man page: http://www.computerhope.com/unix/utee.htm
More 'tee' examples: http://linux.101hacks.com/unix/tee-command-examples/

Edit: I've just re-read your question. Unless your script actively logs to a file, there's no way of viewing the output. If it does, you can use the -f flag of the 'tail' command over SSH to automatically show additions to the file:

```
tail -f /tmp/foo.log
```

Combine this with a 'screen' session, and you can monitor the output and reconnect whenever is convenient. Screen documentation: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-to-use-screen-command-under-linux.html

Answer (score 0):

Adding the `raw_input()` at the end of your script will force you to hit enter before the script executes. Then it will show the output in the terminal window. Just remember to take it out when you're done your initial testing.

Or you could output your Python script to a file then just `tail` that file. Which would be the easiest way.

```
python foo.py > file
```

Comment: I like your second option better. How can I direct the output of the script into a file and tail it? (new to python..)

Comment: @EXEC_BAD_ACCESS updated the answer for you.

Comment: Maybe my question wasn't clear enough. I already started the script through a url directing to the script. 5 hours later I want to see the outputs of the script in real time. Your solution would work only with SSH and there I can already see what's going on through the terminal window